# Which of the following will be true in this case?

Tags: c++, oop

I was asked this in a test and I somehow got confused:

```
Q. If the following is a part of a completely fine C++ program:

     p = new bicycle("Hello world", 2,4);

then, which of the following is true?

1. p is a pointer to a concrete class bicycle.
2. p is a pointer to a concrete class bicycle or some base class (abstract) of bicycle.
3. p is a pointer to a concrete class bicycle or some derived class of bicycle. 

Options: 
A) 1 only
B) 2 only
C) 3 only
D) 1 and 2 both
```

Can you help me what will be the correct solution for this? I would think it would be: `bicycle * p = new ....`

Comment: Are you sure this would compile? Are you missing an asterisk?

Comment: The answer should be "none of the above". `p` is a `bicycle`.

Comment: Yes, it should be `bicycle *`, the code as it stands now shouldn't compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think its probably only `p = new bicycle("Hello world", 2 , 4)`

Comment: Right, my bad. I am sorry, I am editing it. They don't really give us the paper, I am writing the question from my own memory.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Can any of you atleast answer the question now? I made a mistake and I edited it. I said sorry.

Comment: I think the answer should be D.. for (2) You can store the pointer to a derived class in the pointer of a base class.

Comment: @zmbq There isn't enough information to know whether it would compile or not.

Comment: The question is unclear:  the pointer `p` is *allowed* to point to instances of derived classes, but after this line it doesn't.  So it's unclear whether the question is talking about the type of `p` itself, or the type of the object that it points to.

Comment: @juanchopanza,  under what circumstances can it compile?

Comment: @zmbq Obviously if  `bicycle` had a constructor that takes a `bicycle*`.

Comment: You'd think anyone writing a programming exam would know the difference between or and xor. Sloppy, sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is **B**

`bicycle *p = new bicycle();`

This can be a valid declaration for `p` anyway.

Moreover, we can store the pointer to a derived in the pointer of a Base Class.
So, for example there is a class `Cycle` and `bicycle` inherits `Cycle` then ::

`Cycle *p = new bicycle();`
is also a valid statement

Which means `p` can be a pointer to the concrete class bicycle **OR** some base class of bicycle (here cycle). Hence, the answer `B`

Moreover, the answer cannot be **D** since, `p` cannot be a Concrete pointer **AND** also a pointer to base class. Thanks to @bogdan.

Though a lot of things remain unclear from the question. Considering `p` can also be a `void *` (Thanks to @bogdan again :P) which the question clearly misses.

Comment: (1) may not be true, since you just said that `p` could be a pointer to a base class. So, the answer is `B`, since (2) is the only statement that is true in all cases.

Comment: @bogdan You are right I guess. But then option D makes no sense. But, I get a feeling his teacher would have kept option `D` as correct :P because (1) might be true as well.

Comment: Except, of course, that `p` could also be `void*` and that line would still be valid, which makes the entire question poorly specified.

Comment: `D` contains a conjunction, `1 and 2`, and that's not true if (1) is false, which we just established can happen, so `D` is not true.

Comment: @bogdan Technically none are correct. The use of or allows for p to simultaneously be both Bicycle and a subclass of Bicycle.

Comment: @user4581301 That's a bit too much nitpicking, even for me :-). The fact that the statement allows for a case that is never allowed to happen in the context given shouldn't really be a problem. The problem is to find a statement that is true in all cases allowed by the context, and `B` would be such a statement if it weren't for the `void*` case, which the author of the question probably missed - that's what renders all possible answers false.

Comment: @bogdan updated!! Thanks :)

Comment: @user007 Cheers! But I don't quite agree with the reason you gave for `D` not being true. My reasoning is that (1) is false if `p` is a pointer to base, in which case `1 and 2` is also a false statement. Another way to think about it logically is that `A` and `D` are actually equivalent statements, because of the relationship between (1) and (2).